# What sort of C# grammar feature can explain changing type in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am wondering about a function like this (this is from the 'fluent API' but its just an example)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyType>().HasKey(c => new {c.FieldInClassMyType});
```

And so, I wonder in general how that works. I provide a type (`MyType`) and already in the Lambda expression i can use fields from `MyType` that i just provided. What C# feature enables that? Is that an extension function for each type, or...?

Comment: The compiler / Intellisense from Visual Studio can infer types, because of the context. How much do you know about "generics"?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#type-inference-in-lambda-expressions